# how to separate column with char index?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have data like this

```
+-----------+
|lac_ci     |
+-----------+
|12345-78910|
|11111-22222|
|22222-3333 |
|1-23456    |
|2348-6854  |
+-----------+
```

How to separate them like this

```
+-----------+-----+-----+
|lac_ci     |lac  |ci   |
+-----------+-----+-----+
|12345-78910|12345|78910|
|11111-22222|11111|22222|
|22222-3333 |22222|3333 |
|1-23456    |1    |23456|
|2348-6854  |2348 |6854 |
+-----------+-----+-----+
```

I have try

```
update lacci set lac=left(lac, charindex('-',lac_ci)-1)
update lacci set ci=right(ci, charindex('-',lac_ci)-1)
```

But i think this is false query

Comment: What do you think is false in the query? Do you get errors, not the expected result? Also, did you intentionally misspell the tablename (lacci instead of lac_ci)?

Comment: Not the expected result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query:

```
SELECT
    lac_ci,
    LEFT(lac_ci, CHARINDEX('-', lac_ci) - 1) AS lac,
    RIGHT(lac_ci, LEN(lac_ci) - CHARINDEX('-', lac_ci)) AS ci
FROM
    t1
```

will render the data as follows:

```
+-----------+-----+-----+
|lac_ci     |lac  |ci   |
+-----------+-----+-----+
|12345-78910|12345|78910|
|11111-22222|11111|22222|
|22222-3333 |22222|3333 |
|1-23456    |1    |23456|
|2348-6854  |2348 |6854 |
+-----------+-----+-----+
```

`CHARINDEX` will tell the query where the `-` is, but then you have to use the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` operators respectively, to select that portion of the string.

In the case of `LEFT`, it's straightforward, and you were almost there in your logic, if not in the implementation.

For the `RIGHT`, you need to subtract the position of the `-` from full length of the string (that's what `LEN` is doing).

Comment: Instead of `RIGHT + LEN` you can use `SUBSTRING(lac_ci, CHARINDEX('-', lac_ci) + 1, 8000)`

Comment: Be aware that if the lac_ci column does not have a '-', you will get errors